# Roblox Lua not recognizing when boolvalue = true

Tags: lua, roblox

I want it to show a gui when the value is equal to true of "Open".

I have even started the game with the value equaling true and that didn't work. No errors either.

```lua
while script.Parent.Parent.Open.Value == true do
    script.Parent.Visible.Value = true
    script .Parent.Parent.Text2.Visible.Value = true
    break
end
```

I want the two textboxes("Text1" and "Text2" to show up in the screengui named "EndlessPit" to be visible on the screen. No error messages either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using BoolValues, you can simply have your LocalScript observe changes to the value. You can do something like this :

```
local openVal = script.Parent.Parent.Open
local parentGui = script.Parent
local text2 = script.Parent.Parent.Text2

openVal.Changed:Connect(function(value)
    parentGui.Visible = value
    text2.Visible = value
end)
```

This will make it turn the elements on and off whenever the BoolValue changes from true to false or back to true again.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to remove the .Value behind Visible

```lua
while script.Parent.Parent.Open.Value == true do
    print("moose")
    script.Parent.Visible = true
    script .Parent.Parent.Text2.Visible = true
    break
end
```

Comment: actually it did recognize it when I set it to true at the start of the game but it didn't when I changed it to true later on. If someone know the info it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If Open.Value starts as true, this code only loops until it is false. There is nothing that causes the loop to start up again.

Comment: The usage of a `while` makes in this case no sense (because of the `break`). This means, it enters the while ones, then breaks and leaves the loop.
Better use an `if`-statement, `if script.Parent.Parent.Open.Value == true then [your code] end`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it would be helpful to know what `script`'s ancestry looks like, that is, what kind of object its parent is, and so on. Using variables to refer to those objects would be a good start. Also, is this `ScreenGui` called 'EndlessPit' meant to be visible all the time, or just at certain points?

As far as your while-loop goes, could your problem be coming from the fact that you break out of the loop immediately, instead of checking some condition? I do not know the whole story here as you only provided a snippet of code, so a bigger picture and explanation of what exactly you are trying to achieve would be helpful.

Finally, no need to check if `true == true` since `Open` is a `BoolValue`; those kind of equality checks with bools are unnecessary. In the grand scheme of things, they are minute but removing them would optimize your code ever so slightly.